# How add search product by id in function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

i have the code

**categoriesAction.js**

```
import {FETCH_CATEGORIES_START, FETCH_CATEGORIES_SUCCESS, FETCH_CATEGORIES_ERROR} from "./actions-types/categories-actions"
import axios from "axios"

export function fetchCategories() {
  return async dispatch => {
    dispatch(fetchCategoriesStart())
    try {
      const response = await axios.get('/api/category/categories')
      const categories = []
      categories.push(response.data.data)
      dispatch(fetchCategoriesSuccess(categories))
    } catch (e) {
      dispatch(fetchCategoriesError(e))
    }
  }
}

export function fetchCategoriesStart() {
  return{
    type: FETCH_CATEGORIES_START
  }
}

export function fetchCategoriesSuccess(categories) {
  return{
    type: FETCH_CATEGORIES_SUCCESS,
    categories
  }
}

export function fetchCategoriesError(error) {
  return{
    type: FETCH_CATEGORIES_ERROR ,
    error
  }
}
```

**And reducer Code**

```
import {FETCH_CATEGORIES_START, FETCH_CATEGORIES_SUCCESS, FETCH_CATEGORIES_ERROR} from "../actions/actions-types/categories-actions"
const initialState = {
  categories: [],
  loading: false,
  error: null
}

export default function categoriesReducer(state = initialState, action){
  switch (action.type) {
    case FETCH_CATEGORIES_START:
      return {
        ...state, loading: true
      }
    case FETCH_CATEGORIES_SUCCESS:
      return {
        ...state, loading: false, categories: action.categories[0]
      }
    case FETCH_CATEGORIES_ERROR:
      return {
        ...state, loading: false, error: action.error
      }
    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

But when i get category , i need additional search by category ID products and put in object Categories( for example key products with products array) , i.e make another async request . But i can't make async in async function.

```
const response = await axios.get('/api/category/categories')
const categories = []
categories.push(response.data.data)
```

Maybe i am not right create question but i need next logic.

1. Make axios.get for category
2. Get category
3. Make new axios.get by categoryID and response as array products put in object Category
   **Thanks**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am right, you want to fetch the products and add them to the array directly after you fetch the categories, before you dispatch categories to the store? If so, you can just map through the categories:

```
const categoriesWithProducts = await Promise.all(
   categories.map(
      async category => {
         const products = await 'INSERT AXIOS REQUEST HERE';
         return {
            ...category,
            products
         }
      }
   )
)
```

Then pass categoriesWithProducts into the dispatch function.